# "answers" oozes out of accepted-answer green background

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, meta

If you have a question here on Meta.SE with multiple answers, one of which is accepted, it shows up like this on the "favorites" tab of the user activity page (and probably elsewhere):

[image]

No big deal, but I figure it's worth noting.

Comment: I'm not seeing the same thing as the example you are showing. Could you tell us which browser you're using and if you've tried clearing your cache recently?

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Did you check on the profile page? I can repro [on the favourites tab in my profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150235/tim-stone?tab=favorites) in Chrome (dev) and Firefox (latest stable) and the questions tab. The main question views seem fine, though.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. A fix is in the works.