# You forgot to color the answers count with green!

Tags: bug, design

Happens in "bounties" and "questions" tabs of profile page, also happens in all the tabs of [main page](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

If question has answers, "answers" label is written in green. While answers count is ***black***.

> [image]

Comment: Ew, it looks like "answers" is overflowing there on the bottom.

Comment: @bjb I know, already reported not by me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250495/answers-oozes-out-of-accepted-answer-green-background

Comment: @bjb568 don't encourage it

Comment: Aaand it's fixed indefinite time ago.