# The arrow in the upvote button is not properly centred!

Tags: bug, design

OK, let's take this pic of upvote and downvote buttons:

> [image]

Now we'll look carefully at the **downvote** button and rotate it:

> [image]

And now rotate the **upvote** button and look at it:

> [image]

You see it, yeah?

Comment: I think you're taking this crusade ***bit*** too far...

Comment: Just tell me, you prefer to click the downvote button because it is more beautiful and has its arrow properly centered?

Comment: Nope, I don't "prefer" anything - what I agree with I upvote, what I disagree with I downvote. And if there's a grade for "too minor" things, this one is candidate for world record. :)

Comment: @Roo "Stack Exchange doesn't support user modified CSS changes to its sites"  -  waat... You mean I can't report a design bug or post a request about design???

Comment: @Roo ugh, Look at my pics. That's about *vertical* align, not about *horizontal* align as in the  question you pointed. And: "you changed the design" - are you serious...

Comment: SE does not support zoom over 110%

Comment: Please visit the [help center](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help). This is does not make sense. I yet do not understand the purpose of this, also I would like to know what will you achieve if you fix this bug(If it really is).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not constructive.

Comment: @Moose ur abuseman, change ur name. Since which flood it is not constructive?

Comment: It has **20 downvotes**. It's not an issue that needs fixing, and is therefore not constructive.

Comment: @Moose your first argument is invalid :) and wat. It needs to be fixed immediately, I almost fell off my chair once I saw this horrible bug!

Comment: @nicael I'm not sure how to respond to that.

Comment: @Moose wait, you *already* did, so you were sure.

Comment: @Sha Please give me an explanation, what does "too minor" mean. This q is as minor as [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250506/you-forgot-to-color-the-answers-count-with-green) one, but this one is at -12, while *that* one is at +11 :D Logic?

Comment: @nicael colors are not that minor. Making such a huge fuss over 0.0001 of a pixel is.

Comment: This is a disturbing amount of concern about an irrelevant piece of window dressing....

Answer (score 12):

I did my own calculations of this based on the current intended design (without rotating the arrows into right arrows).

I think the picture speaks for itself.

[image]

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

Comment: I think you might have missed the Illuminati connection, without which this answer isn't complete.